# laravel belongsTo not working with one to one relation

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

i have two tables:

```
**plans:**
planId, plan_name

**Users:**
userId, user_name, password, planId
```

i tried to get the name of the plan where i select all users.

this is the users model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Users extends Authenticatable {

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'userId';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_name',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        '_token',
    ];

    public function plan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Plans', 'planId');
    }

    public function validateCredentials( MyUserInterface $user, array $credentials ) {
        $plain = $credentials["password"] . $user->getAuthPasswordSalt();

        return $this->hasher->check( $plain, $user->getAuthPassword() );
    }
}
```

and this is the plan model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Plans extends Model {

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'plans';
    protected $primaryKey = 'planId';

    protected $fillable = [
        'plan_name'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        '_token',
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Users', 'planId');
    }
}
```

when i used:
\App\Users::get();

there is no relations in the output... there is only the users.

what can i do?

i tried to used hasOne and the same issue...

tnx a lot

Comment: Are you actually using the relationship? I.e. `App\Users::with(["plan"])->get();`? Related models/collections aren't included unless you specifically call them.

Comment: tnx this solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can eager load the relationships like this:

```
\App\Users::with('plan')->get();
```

Or add a `$with` property to **always** eager load it when you fetch an user:

```
class Users extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $with = [
        'plan'
    ];
}
```

If you don't want to eager load it, you can access the plan of each user's instance like this:

```
$users = \App\Users::get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    dd($user->plan);
}
```